# $L^{\infty}(μ)=(L^{1}(μ))^*$ ( Dual space of $L^{1}(μ)$ )

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $a,b\in X$ . define $μ(\{a\})=1$ , $μ(\{b\})=μ(X)=\infty$ and $μ(\varnothing)=0$

I don't know the below statement is true or not !

$L^{\infty}(μ)=(L^{1}(μ))^*$ ( dual space of $L^{1}(μ)$ )
In my opinion that's false but i can't find Counterexample .

Can somebody help me?

Comment: How many points does the set $X$ have? Does it have any point other than $a,b$? What are the subsets of $X$ whose measure is $0$?

Comment: @Crostul : $X$ is arbitrary set and at least has points $a\, and \, b$

Comment: You always have the natural continuous linear map $j\colon L^{\infty}(\mu) \to (L^1(\mu))^{\ast}$ given by $j(g)\colon f \mapsto \int fg\,d\mu$. You need to check whether it is a bijection. So a) is it injective, b) is it surjective? If either answer is "No", you don't have the natural identification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Crostul's remark let us assume $a$ and $b$ are the only points (or the only ones having nonzero measure).

Then $L^1$ is canonically isomorphic to the set of scalars (every scalar determines exactly one value that a function can take at $a$). Its dual is then the same set of scalars (as a vector space it has dimension 1). Note that a function with a nonzero value at $b$ can never be integrable.

The space $L^\infty$ consists of the essentially bounded functions so it is a two-dimensional vector space.

This is the counterexample you wanted. If we drop the assumption and consider an $X$ that has subsets of finite nonzero measure not containing $a$ then the two spaces $(L^1)^*$ and $L^\infty$ might or might not happen to be isomorphic. But even when they are isomorphic the isomorphism will never be the canonical one. Any function class in $L^\infty$ taking a nonzero value on $b$ and zero everywhere else will correspond to the zero functional in the dual of $L^1.$